# How to match a pattern after a pattern in regex, using groups, negations, lookarounds

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

I have a pattern `" -[^ ]* "`, the quotes are here to show the spaces. I want to match everything after it until this pattern again is encountered

something like this

```
(?<= -[^ ]* )[^( -[^ ]* )]*
```

or in a compact form

```
p = ( -[^ ]* )

(?<=p)[^p]*
```

the problem is that i cannot use `*` inside `(?<= -[^ ]* )` statement and i cannot use `()` in `[^( -[^ ]* )]`. In both cases these characters are treated literally

Comment: You mean `" -[^ ]* [\s\S]*?(?= -[^ ]* |$)"`? See https://regex101.com/r/UIQKoU/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^( -[^ ]* )]*` is *negated character class*, it matches characters different from round brackets, spaces, hyphen, caret, and so on.

Use

```js
-[^ ]* ((?:(?! -[^ ]* ).)*)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/rE3bQV/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^ ]*                    any character except: ' ' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         -                       ' -'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^ ]*                    any character except: ' ' (0 or more
                                 times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: it's working great but, it's also including the pattern on left side. i want to match every thing that is between the two occurrences of the pattern. i want to exclude the pattern in the match

Comment: @Hammad You have your value in Group 2. See how your values are highlighted in green at https://regex101.com/r/rE3bQV/1. Alternative: `-[^ ]* \K((?:(?! -[^ ]* ).)*)`, see  https://regex101.com/r/rE3bQV/2. Or in JavaScript, .NET: `(?<=-[^ ]* )((?:(?! -[^ ]* ).)*)`, see https://regex101.com/r/rE3bQV/3

Comment: thanks, it is working. i was using sublime text to check the results. it was showing different results